# Top Div tag changes it position

Tags: javascript, css

I have a very strange problem.

Below is the link
http://protestserver.com/Design3

My problem when you enter a zip code, please enter 99999 then a loading div shows up. but that div tag changes the position of my logo slightly.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

check the sizes of the div. Usually if the position is relative, other divs move if their widths/heights exceeds the wrappers height/width. If you're using px, I suggest you use % instead.

Comment: Thank for quick reply.
I have used the % but still the same problem persist.

Comment: how did it exactly change position? I tried it and somehow I didn't see any changes. what is the picture that changed position?

Comment: try opening it in another browser. or maybe the resolution of your monitor?

Comment: When I enter the zip code the logo changes the position slightly to the right, when the loding div tag shows up.

this is happening to me on all browsers.
chrome, Firefox, IE10

Comment: I look into your code and I notice that the logo div is not inside the wrapper. try inserting it into the wrapper.